# failing to build gazebo from source due to not being able to download libraries

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Im trying to build gazebo from source for the gz-sim github:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim

from this tutorial linked in the github:
https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6.1/install.html#source-install

but when I get to the part where you install the libraries, this is what I get:

```
sudo apt -y install   $(sort -u $(find . -iname 'packages-'`lsb_release -cs`'.apt' -o -iname 'packages.apt' | grep -v '/\.git/') | sed '/ignition\|sdf/d' | tr '\n' ' ')
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package libgz-fuel-tools9-dev
    E: Unable to locate package libgz-gui8-dev
    E: Unable to locate package libgz-msgs10-dev
    E: Unable to locate package libgz-rendering8-dev
    E: Unable to locate package libgz-sensors8-dev
    E: Unable to locate package libgz-transport13-dev
```

what am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28902/failing-to-build-gazebo-from-source-due-to-not-being-able-to-download-libraries./) by [ryn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134869/ryn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured it out now. I had two problems.

Firstly, Its confusing knowing what gazebo version to use with what ros2 version. and which one to use isn't immediately obvious. Following the below guide, I saw that my version of ROS2(foxy), only supported citadel.
https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation

(or if that link is dead, if you're using an LTS ROS2 version(foxy), use gazebo(citadel), or if you're using the latest ROS2, use the latest version of gazebo(garden)

Second, I found the install from source guide for Ubuntu  + gazebo citadel here:
https://gazebosim.org/docs/citadel/install_ubuntu_src

---

Originally posted by [ryn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134869/ryn/) with karma: 3 on 2023-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0